# Difference between strictly increasing and increasing.

Tags: calculus, functions

I know that ,based on definitions, in the interval $(a,b)$

For increasing functions, $f(a) \leq f(b)$ and $f'(x) \geq 0$

For strictly increasing functions, $f(a)<f(b)$ and $f'(x)>0$

However,

For example, I am given a question:

Given that $y=4x^3 +3x^2 -6x -7$, find the range of values of $x$ for which $y$ is decreasing.

For $y$ to be decreasing, 
$\frac{dy}{dx} \leq 0$

So, $-1\leq x\leq\frac12$ right?

But for strictly decreasing, $-1<x<\frac12$ right?

Then for increasing, it should be $x \leq -1$ and $x\geq \frac12$

For strictly increasing, it should be  $x< -1$ and also $x \geq \frac12$ (I heard it can start from $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ )

Basically, the problem is what type of inequality sign do I use for which case?

Yes, I did see the other posts on this topic and some quora posts. But I'm still lost.

Comment: Strictly increasing does not require the function to be differentiable, not that the derivative, if it exists, be strictly positive everywhere. The function $x \mapsto x^3$ is strictly increasing but the derivative is zero at $x=0$.

Comment: A function is *increasing* if for all $a < b$ implies that $f(a) \le f(b)$, and *strictly increasing* if for all $a < b$ implies that $f(a) < f(b)$.  These are the definitions you should have in mind.  A consequence of these definitions is that (strictly) increasing functions will have nonnegative derivatives (when they have derivatives at all).  However, even a strictly increasing function can have points with zero derivative (e.g. $x \mapsto x^3$ is strictly increasing, and has derivative zero at $x=0$).

Comment: However if the question asks to find the range at which the function is strictly increasing then what inequality sign do I use? And do I have to include the stationary points or exclude?

Comment: If a continuous function is strictly increasing on an interval $(a,b)$ then it is also strictly increasing on the interval $[a,b]$. In your example, the function is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,-1]$ and on $\left[\frac{1}{2},\infty\right)$ and strictly decreasing on the interval $\left[-1,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. [Assuming, of course, that $a$ and $b$ are in the domain.]

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales So, the example that I have given, the function is strictly increasing and increasing in the same interval right? The same should go for the interval for strictly decreasing and decreasing too right?

Comment: Yes. And notice that in this context the concepts of increasing, strictly increasing, etc. are defined only for intervals, not for singleton points.

Comment: Note that continuity is important. $f(x)=x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ is increasing on the interval $[0,1)$ but not on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Lastly, is there any difference between the set of values where $x$ is strictly increasing and the set of values where $x$ is increasing? Assuming the function is differentiable and continuous everywhere. It seems to me that $f'(x) \geq 0$ whether it is finding the set of values of $x$ where $f(x)$ is strictly increasing or increasing.

Comment: For a function $f$ which is continuous and differentiable everywhere, $f$ is increasing on an interval if and only if it is strictly increasing on that interval. If you want to talk about "increasing at a point" that will require a different definition than "increasing on an interval."

Comment: Oh, so there's no difference when the questions ask for strictly increasing for that interval or increasing in that interval ? Wow,thanks so much for clearing that major doubt of mine. However, for a discontinuous function, there interval for increasing and strictly increasing is the same too right? As long as we can take note what where its discontinuous at at like you said.

Comment: A function with derivative in $[a,b]$ will be both increasing and strictly increasing in $[a,b]$ if (but not "only if") $f'(x)>0$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. This also implies that isolated points with $f'(x)=0$ don't change these conclusions. However, if $f'(x)=0$ over $[c,d]\subset [a,b]$ ($c<d$, of course), then $f$ is constant over $[c,d]$, and so is still true that $f$ is increasing in $a,b$ but is NOT strictly increasing.

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum based on what you said,  $f(x)$ is an increasing function when $f'(x) \geq 0$ but for a strictly increasing function, $f'(x)$ does not need to more than $0$ and can be $0$ at times like when $f(x)=x^3$. For a strictly increasing function, we have no choice but to fall back to the definition right?

Comment: If we extend our definitions to sets which are not intervals, a function $f$ discontinuous at $x=x_0 \in [a,b]$ but with $f'(x)\geq 0$ everywhere else, is increasing over $[a,x_0)$ and $(x_0,b]$. If we also have $f(x_0^-)\leq f(x_0+)$ then $x<y \implies f(x)\leq f(y)$ is true for every $x,y \in [a,b]\backslash \{x_0\}$ and we would say $f$ is increasing there. Otherwise, you can just say is increasing in each interval but not over $[a,b]\backslash \{x_0\}$. Anyway, it is customary only to talk about increasing and decreasing over sets that are intervals.

Comment: @ArcNeoepi That's it. If $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$ (and differentiable) need have $f'(x)\geq 0$ at every point, but if it is strictly increasing need not be the case that $f'(x)>0$ at every point (although it cannot be 0 over any subinterval).

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum "(although it cannot be 0 over any subinterval)" means it can't be a point of inflexion for strictly increasing function?

Comment: It can be. By subinterval i meant to exclude those like $[c,c]$ which are just a point. If $f'>0$ at every point of $[a,b]$ but ONE (or two, or any finite number of points), then it is for sure strictly increasing over $[a,b]$ (and yes, that stationary point would also be an inflexion point, that is, a change of concavity).

Comment: Last question then, in the interval $[a,b]$, can I still say $f$ is strictly increasing if $f'>0$ but at $[a,a]$ and $[b,b]$ , $f'=0$ ? Yes right?

Comment: Yes, you can. =)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I have cleared all of my misunderstandings for this concept!

Comment: A proof to such affirmation is that given any two $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $x<y$, the Mean Value Theorem (or Lagrange's Theorem) implies that there is a $c \in (x,y)$ such that $$f(y)-f(x)=f'(c)\cdot (y-x)$$ and so is $f(y)-f(x)>0$, that is $f(x)<f(y)$. This is so because $a \leq x<c<y\leq b$, and then $f'(c)>0$... because $c$ is not $a$ nor $b$.

Comment: More intuitively, if you take $x,y \in [a,b]$ with $x<y$, even if $x=a$ or $y=b$, no matter how close they are, $[x,y]$ contains (infinitely many) points where $f'>0$, and so $f$ has to increase its value going from $x$ to $y$.\\ So no: just one point with $f'=0$ does not change the conclusions.